# Do functional languages use information from the caller to do type inference?

Tags: types, functional-programming, type-inference, ml

Consider functions f1 and f2 in for example Haskell or ML. Suppose f2 calls f1. Does type inference just use the information of what f1 can call, which amounts to just looking at the definition of f1. Or does it also look at how f2 calls f1 when doing type inference on f1. For example f2 might pass in literals when calling f1 which would restrict the argument types of f1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type systems don't use information about the caller to determine the types a function could handle -- that would be both overly restrictive and impossible to achieve in general. E.g., suppose (Haskell)

```
aList :: [Int]
aList = [1,2,3]

one = head aList
```

would henceforth restrict the type of `head` from `[a] -> a` to `[Int] -> Int`; afterwards, `head ["hello", "world"]` would be impossible and we'd have to redefine `head` the next time we want to use it on a different type. However, *in the context* of the definition of `one`, `head` actually has the type `[Int] -> Int` as the variables in its type get instantiated. But that doesn't change the global definition of `head` or its type.

(In practice, a compiler may specialize a function that it knows is going to be called in only a few situations and adapt the code to the specific types being passed in, as long as it doesn't change program semantics.)

Comment: That is not quite correct, see my reply.

Answer (score 8):

That depends on whether the function `f1` is bound by a declaration or by other means (e.g. as a function parameter to `f2`). In the former case, its type can be generalised to be polymorphic, in the latter it cannot, and unresolved parts are determined by the context. And even in the former case, additional rules may apply, such as ML's value restriction.

Consider this example in Haskell:

```hs
f1 = \x -> x  -- polymorphic: f1 :: a -> a
f2 = f1 True  -- instantiates f1 :: Bool -> Bool

f2 = let f1 = \x -> x in f1 True  -- likewise

f2 = (\f1 -> f1 True) (\x -> x)  -- here, f1 cannot be polymorphic,
                                 -- so the lambda is restricted to Bool -> Bool by the call
```

and similarly in SML:

```ml
val f1 = fn x => x  (* polymorphic, f1 : 'a -> 'a *)
val f2 = f1 true

val f2 = let val f1 = fn x => x in f1 true end  (* likewise *)

val f2 = (fn f1 => f1 true) (fn x => x)  (* f1 monomorphic, f1 : bool -> bool *)

val f1 = let _ = 0 in fn x => x end  (* value restriction applies, f1 cannot be polymorphic *)
val f2 = f1 true  (* determines type f1 : bool -> bool *)
```

For clarity, I'm not using abbreviated function declaration syntax here.

Comment: Isn't this a similar idea to the one mentioned in the Cardelli paper on type checking with the example of `f = let g a = a in (g 1, g True)` vs `let f g = (g 1, g True)` ? The idea being in the second one the type of `g` cannot be inferred properly because you can't unify both `Int` and `Bool`, but the first one can be because the type of `g` only depends on what's in the body of `g`.

Comment: @Wes, well yes, Cardelli uses that example to explain _why_ function arguments are always treated as monomorphic in ML-like type systems (namely, so that type inference can be done using simple unification).